# Masking Landsat-8 and Modis (Aqua) with same shape file doesn't result in same shape

Tags: modis, landsat-8, extract-by-mask, coregistration

I was trying to mask Landsat-8 and Modis (Aqua image). FYI, I have  converted the MODIS image to the same projection as Landsat and same resolution as 30m.  Finally once i am done with masking using the shape file the result comes out as shown below in QGIS. I have two questions regarding the same

1) As you can see **width** and **height** of both the output is not same. It differs by 1. I have tried using with different shape file also but again the issue remains same. I always get height 1 less than MODIS. Though i also tried setting the value of `nodata` to be 0. But no luck.

2) As you can see below both the images are not overlapping perfectly in QGIS screenshot. Moreover, their extent is also different. So, how do i overcome this problem?

**Landsat:**

[image: Landsat]

**Modis**

[image: Modis]

**Overlay of Modis on top of Landsat**
[image]

Comment: Mask selects all the pixels which at least partially intersect the mask. In your two images the pixels are not aligned. I would warp both images into 30 m pixel size with gdalwarp by using the -tap (target aligned pixels) option.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. What could be the reason of height not matching in both the cases?